# How do I notify a Slack group about a Google Calendar event the day before it happens?

Tags: google-calendar, slack

I want to send a notify to a Slack group for events a day before.

There is a IFTTT recipe for `Google calendar` to `Slack`, but this recipe notifies maximum 45 minutes before the event.

https://ifttt.com/applets/177144p-before-an-event-starts-post-a-reminder-to-slack

Is there a workaround for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an app you can connect with your slack channels and get events notifications from Google right there: [Slack App](https://get.slack.help/hc/en-us/articles/206329808-Connect-Google-Calendar-to-Slack)

The above link contains the documentation and link to the app to connect that app to your Slack channel.

If you are using this app, you can change the reminder date right from your Google Calendar's event entry, e.g., if you want to get a reminder 30 minutes before the event starts, just do so on your event and you'll get a reminder 30 minutes before the event starts. Same goes for the a day before. Change the reminder setting of that event to a day before the event starts and it's done.